Как ускорить работу OpenCV_Annotations
У меня есть папка с положительными образами, коих 1000 штук. Они заранее вырезаны и подготовлены. Но при запуске OpenCV_Annotations надо области на фотографии все равно размечать. Есть ли какой-то способ ускорить данное дело?

Пока только вариант - узнавать через код x1x2y1y2 координаты картинки и выводить это значение в выходной файл.
